# Passport ensureAuthenticated

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I want to implement a login with **Passport.js** and **Github Strategy**. Here is the code I use:

```js
...

/* Ensure Auth function */
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next()
    else res.redirect('/');
}

/* Some modules */
global.passport = require('passport');
global.GithubStrategy = require('passport-github2').Strategy;
global.util = require('util');
global.session = require('express-session');
global.bodyParser = require('body-parser');
global.methodOverride = require('method-override');
global.partials = require('express-partials');
global.request = require('request');

/* Passport */
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
   done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done){
   done(null, obj);
});
passport.use(new GithubStrategy({
        clientID: config.githubID,
        clientSecret: config.githubSecret,
        callbackURL: config.githubURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
        process.nextTick(function(){
            return done(null, profile);
        });
    }
));
app.use(partials());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/* Controllers */
app.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github', {scope: ['user:email']}), function(req, res){});
app.get('/auth/github/callback', passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/' }), function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
});
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
   req.logout();
   res.redirect('/');
});
```

I search a lot in Passport.js docs, but I can't find answers for this questions:

- Why, in my case, the session **doesn't save the authentification**? For example, if I set the ensureAuthenticated middleware on a route, it always redirect me to /, where is the login form.
- Why I can't access user info from **req.user** to see user infos?
- Why the **logout** route doesn't work?

Comment: Haha I'm currently sitting with the same issue. If you inspect your requests (either using your Chrome/Firefox developer tools or POSTMAN), is your session cookie being returned after your authentication request? (It should contain the key 'connect.sid' and a session id value)

Comment: Did you solve it? My idea is that it doesn't save session, but I want to store sessions is Mongo/Redis. I guess this gonna work.

Comment: Right, I did get it to work last night, I'll write up an answer soon detailing the stuff I did. Before I do, do you have a specific frontend like Angular? or do you prepare your views in your NodeJS server?

Comment: Ah I see you're using 'partials', i think it's safe to assume you're rendering your views on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Foreword/Preamble**

I had the same issue with the [Local Strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local). I don't have much information on the architecture of your system, however my system used the following:

- PassportJS (w/ Local Strategy)
- ExpressJS handling sessions & routing (w/ a Redis MemoryStore)
- NodeJS server
- AngularJS 2 frontend

**Things to checkout**

1. **CORS** played a major role with this issue.

I used the [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) library to alleviate the issues I had there. In particular, I made the following change to the configuration:

```
let cors_config = {
    origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    credentials: true
};
```

This configures your CORS settings to include the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true header in the preflight requests.

2. Make sure your **memory store & session is configured correctly**

Start off by not having a specified memory store (the default is the LocalStore) and work from there onwards. I see you're not using one now, so just read on anyway.

```
server.use(session({
    secret: "secret_c0de",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false//,
    //store: new redis_store(redis_settings)
}));
```

Check to see if, when you're authenticating, that afterwards your session cookie is returned after authenticating. It should contain a key-value with a key of 'connect.sid', your session ID.

If you're not getting a session cookie, then you know that your session might not be configured correctly, in which case you should:

- Check the load order of your 'use' calls
- Try and identify any errors or issues with your session handling code

If you're receiving your cookie, but the isAuthenticated() check is failing in subsequent requests, this usually hints at your MemoryStore not working.

- If you're initially using a LocalStore, this doesn't require much configuration, and thus again, hints to an issue with your session configuration
- If you're using a store like Redis, try and listen to the [Redis events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#connection-and-other-events) (mainly 'connect' and 'error') and log the output to the console so you can see if it's working at all.

**Thing's I noticed in your code**

- Check your serialization functions, you're serializing the entire user object.

This is more of an optimization, but have noticed people have had more success just serializing the user's ID and deserializing it.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done){
    User.findById(obj, function(err, user){
        if(err){/*code to handle error with not finding user*/}
        done(null, user);
    });
});
```

- You should require the [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) since sessions use a session cookie.

**To answer your questions**

- Why, in my case, the session doesn't save the authentification?

Session creation is broken in your application, so you should try and debug this. As mentioned above, you should check if the session ID is being returned in a session cookie after your authentication request and move on from there.

- Why I can't access user info from req.user to see user infos?

The user is injected after a successful deserialization attempt from Passport. In your case, the session is never created in the first place, never serialized into your MemoryStore, and thus can never be deserialized (since it doesn't exist).

- Why the logout route doesn't work?

req.logout() will only work on a successful session being created. 
Judging by the other code and info you provided, I assume that's what you're referring to.

Hope you find some valuable information here, feel free to comment if you'd like to chat about something in particular! :)

Answer (score 0):

The  best source to understand and implent the code for passport based authentication was here. check it once
https://www.coursera.org/learn/server-side-development/lecture/Clovu/passport